# Programmatically retrieving custom Reports from Dynamics CRM 2016 SQL Database

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016, rdl

We have over 100 custom reports that need to be retrieved from our CRM. I know this can be done one at a time through the UI but I need to create a 'bulk download' utility.

Searching through the database I found tables for the default reports but not our custom ones. On the server's file system I found the default report `.rdl` files but not our custom ones.

Does anybody know where the custom reports reside (SQL database or filesystem)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those reports will be stored in Reporting server, which is configured during installation of CRM.

I found [this blog](http://vinay.inkeysolutions.com/2013/08/ssrs-download-all-rdl-files-from-report.html?m=1), which talks about downloading rdl files in bulk.